# Cannot clip raster by extent because my layers list too long

Tags: qgis, raster

I try to clip a raster by his own extent as I want to assign "no_data" pixel a value.

But when I try to do it, my layer list is too long and I cannot take the one I want to. I cannot moove on this window as well..

[image: see here]

Has this ever happened to someone else?

Comment: Sorry but moove what to where?

Comment: I would suggest using a fresh QGIS instance with only the layers you are working with, to keep things more manageable. You can drag and drop layers from the layer tree of one QGIS project to another. This preserves their symbology and labelling etc.